# Is it possible to charge/discharge this cap fast enough?

Tags: power-electronics, bridge-rectifier

What I have, is a common 12-pulse rectifier with its bridges in series and I included a snubber between DC-link and rectifier output. Is important to note that all inductances before the rectifier are small in order to minimize its impact on this snubber performance. Also, I cleaned the circuit from scopes and control of IGBTs in order to visualize in a better way this system.

[image]

The main Idea of this snubber is to give a semi-triangular shape to the current by following a reference (each snubber has it reference which is the same shape but shifted in 30°). The [background theory and reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsH4T.png) for obtaining this currents, is that doing so, I should have sinusoidal currents at the transformer's primary winding or the AC busbar which is connected this rectifier.

Now, the snubber is supposed to work like this: If output current from snubber is greater than reference, then IGBTs must be turned OFF in order to charge this capacitor and lower output current. Otherwise, if output current is less than reference IGBTs must be turned on, discharging this capacitor and increasing this current. Until now, I can only get this working using DC voltage sources instead of rectifiers  (250kV each bridge) as you can see in this picture:

[image]

And when using a proper 12-pulse rectifier I get this.

[image]

Here the tracking of the reference (green) is really great but for some reason the voltage across the capacitor increases until my simulation crashes. The main idea of this snubber is to turn off both IGBTs when voltage across capacitor is aprox 1V in order to reduce losses while switching, however, if I add that condition in both cases (with DC Voltage Sources and 12-pulse rectifier) the output current from snubber (red) takes a long time to discharge when the snubber have to track the lower sections of this triangular reference.

Any suggestion or recommendation would be truly appreciated as I don't really know what to do instead of changing values of my system without knowing why.

EDIT: I'm using PLECS 3.5.2, if you think something in the logic control should be wrong then I can upload pictures of it too.

Comment: Kindly explain where you got this design and why you call this a 'snubber', to me it sounds more like a power factor corrector.

Comment: You write that "...all inductances before the rectifier are small...", yet I see "L: 1e-3", doesn't that mean 1 mH, and how is that 'small'--or is this common in HVDC transmission?

Comment: @HarryH 'Method and apparatus to reduce current distortion in line-commutated rectifiers' M.E Villablanca, published in IET Power Electronics (2007). There he called this circuit (IGBTs + Diodes + Cap configuration) a 'snubber' which basically at the time was just an IGBT with huge losses. That is why he designed this 'snubber' configuration to achieve soft-switching. As he is my teacher I just get used to the term, however I would call it a current converter.

Comment: Have you got a link to that article please? What I understood is that a snubber is a contraption that reduces switching losses, but I could have missed a more general definition.

Comment: Your input voltage is 66kV, your transformer looks to me as 1:1, how does each bridge make 250 kV out of this?

Comment: Coming back to the function of that contraption... its purpose is to make the input current sinusoidal and it's connected between rectifier and DC link. Definitely a power factor (pf) corrector, although not necessarily to correct the phase lag rather than the current's harmonics, but still then it improves the pf.

Comment: @HarryH Here I uploaded the document I mentioned before and I'm looking for the updated one which includes this new circuit (although the background theory is the same). As regards the 250 kV it was another simulation I did using two DC voltage sources as these 'bridges' to see if maybe the problem appeared when using a 12-pulse rectifier chich output voltage is not as constant, of course, as both DC sources.
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lax5r6jgsIodX7IJ4hEeZWZXWTOK5Eu3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And here is the one using the circuit used in this thread. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85ZyFc5rvCQVnNKTnNpZUJWQm5DNzNfNTE5MElaSmJwZlZn/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

> The main idea of this snubber is to turn off both IGBTs when voltage across capacitor is aprox 1V in order to reduce losses while switching, however, if I add that condition in both cases (with DC Voltage Sources and 12-pulse rectifier) the output current from snubber (red) takes a long time to discharge when the snubber have to track the lower sections of this triangular reference.

So this is your question?
When the transistor is off, current through the contraption should continue to flow, only against an inverse voltage. I.e.: the diodes should conduct and the capacitors discharge; about as fast as they have charged.
So I think there's a fault in your model and/or steering logic.
I don't have the time to analyse the logic and simulation model, so maybe someone else can help you with that.